# ffmpeg - Frames flip upside-down when using -c:v copy

Tags: ffmpeg, copy, flip

I tried to just copy (a period of time of) an AVI-Video into another newly created AVI-file using ffmpeg's copy option.
(On Windows 32-bit)

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Temp\zzz\myAvi.avi" -c copy -t 00:00:10 "C:\Temp\zzz\myAviNew.avi"
```

Why are the pictures flipped upside-down in the resulting file ?
(Also the generated new audio is a little distorted.)

Using the same command again on the newly created file will not flip them back again - the pictures stay upside down.
Why this? Is it a bug?

Console brings the following output:

```
 ffmpeg version N-50911-g9efcfbe Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 13 2013 21:26:48 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libg
sm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libo
pencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-li
bschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-lib
twolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enabl
e-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 19.100 / 52. 19.100
  libavcodec     55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavformat    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavdevice    54.  4.100 / 54.  4.100
  libavfilter     3. 45.103 /  3. 45.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[avi @ 02537ba0] non-interleaved AVI
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\Temp\zzz\Hase.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:35.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 171375 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgra, 768x576, 12 tbr, 12 tbn, 12 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, avi, to 'C:\Temp\zzz\HaseNew.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf55.0.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgra, 768x576, q=2-31, 12 tbn, 12 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, 141
1 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   11 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=   19162kB time=00:00:00.91 bitrate=171242.4kbit
frame=   16 fps= 12 q=-1.0 size=   27874kB time=00:00:01.33 bitrate=171255.5kbit
...
...
...
frame=  120 fps=5.4 q=-1.0 size=  209083kB time=00:00:09.99 bitrate=171280.6kbit
frame=  121 fps=5.5 q=-1.0 Lsize=  210834kB time=00:00:10.08 bitrate=171288.2kbi
ts/s
video:209088kB audio:1723kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.0112
76%

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: seems like a bug to me, I'd maybe report it on trac.ffmpeg.org ...

Answer (score 0):

The issue might come from your input file. The copy does exactly what it says, it copies the bitstream from your input container to an output container. When an issue arise, most of the time it is because some data has not been passed from the input to the output, (such as metadata) since video data can't be modified using copy.

Regarding your specific issue, video files can contain metadata to specify the rotation to which be played to the video player.

To add that information back to the output container, you need to add the following attribute to the ouput.

```
-metadata:s:v:0 rotate=180
```

Your initial command should look like :

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Temp\zzz\myAvi.avi" -c copy -t 00:00:10 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=180 "C:\Temp\zzz\myAviNew.avi"
```